# Как работать с видео и аудио в C?

Tags: c++, c

Ну... Вопрос слегка "общего толка". Как на C (можно и C++) работать с медиа файлами? Я имею в виду действия вида:

1.Распознать формат видео (avi, mp4, т д)

2.Распознать кодек (h264, hevc, AV-1, т д)

3.Посчитать FPS

4.Работать с кадрами видео напрямую

5.Распознать звук из видео и отделить его

6.Реверсировать музыку

7.Посчитать пиксели в изображении

И т д.

Хотелось бы узнать, с чего начать изучение данного вопроса. И да, прошу кросс-платформенные варианты, т е не привязанные (и тем более не являющиеся сами) к интерфейсу конкретной ОС.

Comment: Первым в голову приходит очевидный ffmpeg

Comment: Ffmpeg это утилита, а мне нужны методы/библиотеки для C или C++. Проще говоря, нужно работать программно.

Comment: Не, ffmpeg это в первую очередь набор сишных библиотек

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs